# How to resolve confilct of symbols?

Tags: c++, g++

I have a library `libA.so` which have class `MyClass`, and I have a library `libB.so` which also have class with name `MyClass`. The classes are used into the libraries only. Firstly my program loads `libA.so` then `libB.so`.

Problem is that `libB.so` uses `MyClass` from `libA.so`, but must use its own `MyClass`.

How to resolve the problem, without rename or using namespace?

g++ version is 5.4.0

Comment: are you using `namespaces`?

Comment: No I am not. Using namespace resolves the problem, but I don't want use it

Answer (score 0):

With dynamic linking, you can use a [linker version script](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/VERSION.html) to restrict which symbols are exported from the library.  If you ensure that all conflicting symbols are local (or hidden, as they are sometimes called), then the conflict goes away because the symbols are strictly internal to the library.

Managing symbol visibility in this way is a good practice anyway, and it can reduce program load time, too, because the dynamic linker has to process fewer symbols.

Answer (score 0):

It's need to use flag `-fvisibility=hidden` and mark function and classes which should be exportable by `__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))`.

Mark function and classes which should be hidden by `__attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")))`

For instance:

```
#define LIB_EXPORT __attribute__((visibility ("default")))
class LIB_EXPORT MyClass
{
    //realisation
};
```